# Polkit rule to allow a user restart systemd service

Tags: linux, centos, polkit

I created `/etc/polkit-1/rules.d/00-manage-docker-daemon.rules` file with following rule to allow members of "agroup" to administer (stop/start/restart) docker.service (Centos 7):

```
// Allow agroup members to manage docker.service;
// fall back to implicit authorization otherwise.
polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
  if (action.id == "org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units" &&
    action.lookup("unit") == "docker.service") &&
    subject.isInGroup("agroup"))
    {
      return polkit.Result.YES;
    }
});
```

I have restarted "polkit" systemd service (I was not sure if needed), unfortunately users beings members of "agroup" are not able to run the commands - they are prompted for root password:

```
$ id
uid=17870(user) gid=17870(user) groups=17870(user),17897(agroup) context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
$ systemctl restart docker.service
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units ===
Authentication is required to manage system services or units.
Authenticating as: root
Password:
```

How to get this stuff working? Is there anything missing in my configuration?

Comment: I had the same problem and found this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61480914/using-policykit-to-allow-non-root-users-to-start-and-stop-a-service).  It looks like it doesn't work in CentOS 7 the way it should.